# How does capacitor C2 discharge?

Tags: capacitor, bjt

I'm a beginner and now I'm learning how this circuit works.

This circuit is transistor tester.
[image]

I wonder how capacitor C2 discharges, because it needs to go to the other side of capacitor, but it can't because the BE junction blocks it.

In my book they said C2 discharges through ground. Is this true? Does that mean it flows through R5>>ground>>9V>>R3>>R1>> and the other side of the capacitor?

Comment: See the arrow labelled (1)? The BE junction is forward biased, so it doesn't block the current. T1 is the source of that current. The reverse current is shown by arrow (2), which follows the path you described. R3 is the source of that current.

Comment: Does capacitor C2 discharge ?      In this circuit C2 is non polarized capacitor I add positive sign to show that now it charged this side .

Comment: Yes. Once C2 approaches full charge, the current through it drops low enough that "NPN (TOT)" cuts off. This causes T1 to cut off as well, and R5 pulls the positive end of C2 to ground. This means that the other end of C2 becomes negative with respect to ground, reinforcing the fact that both transistors are off. Now the only path for current is through R3 and R1 -- arrow (2). Since this current is the reverse of the charging current, C2 now discharges -- relatively slowly, since R1 is so large relative to R3 and R5.

Comment: As it does so, the negative voltage at the base of "NPN (TOT)" rises, and once it becomes positive by enough to turn the transistor on, the cycle repeats. This is a form of "relaxation oscillator". Don't be confused by the little sine wave notations in the schematic -- the actual waveform is quite different.

Comment: @DaveTweed..... Thank you very much . So it discharge through R5>>ground>>9V>>R3>>R1>> and the other side of the capacitor path.

Comment: Play with this https://tinyurl.com/2y8gpu6g

Comment: So if it charge as picture https://drive.google.com/file/d/12wOoLKGbYp1PKxAut9bOVpINPLnKZr-K/view?usp=drivesdk , It will follow this path right?

Comment: @Heroz Yes, it will follow this path during charging phase.

Comment: Sorry in this picture https://drive.google.com/file/d/12wOoLKGbYp1PKxAut9bOVpINPLnKZr-K/view?usp=drivesdk it charged at positive side and when it will  discharge follow this path right?

Comment: @G36........... Wave form in picture it's not AC right?

Comment: Not AC? I think they show the  "signal phase".  And this picture is showing the charging phase https://drive.google.com/file/d/12wOoLKGbYp1PKxAut9bOVpINPLnKZr-K/view